# Android Popups: How To

Tags: android

How can I make a popup window in Android with simple yes / no buttons?

Answer (score 3):

Noam,

It sounds like an `AlertDialog` is exactly what you want: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Answer (score 1):

Check out the different views!
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

also you can edit main.xml and drag/drop buttons onto it (it will autofill in the XML, and then you can redit them)

edit: Also I believe one of the "samples" has a basic example in the android SDK

Cheers~